# 'required' in HTML is not functioning

Tags: html

I want to make some of my fields mandatory in my HTML code. To do so, I have used the command 'required' which makes the input fields mandatory. Unfortunately the 'required' command is not functioning in my code. Can any one help me out with this?

The code is given below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="name" />  <br />
    <b>Age:</b><input type="text" name="age" required > <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing a form element so the browser doesn't know what you're submitting

Use this code instead

```
<form action="someActionScript">
    <b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="name" />  <br />
    <b>Age:</b><input type="text" name="age" required /> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here's a simple example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBQzdX

Cheers

Comment: Thank you Isabel Inc. Actually in the original code I enclosed everything inside 'form' element but the problem came due to improper end tag in preceding line.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Do mark this as the answer for other people if it helped you. Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a form to submit or pass values.
Now you can use this to achieve

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="YourUrlToSendValues" method="SetPostOrGetMethod">
    <b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="name" />  <br />
    <b>Age:</b><input type="text" name="age" required> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Rajpal Singh. The issue is solved. I used 'form' in my original code. The error was due to improper end tag.

Comment: Welcome @ManikumarPerla !